# Why is it always possible to construct an unidirectional data flow using Angular2?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular, zone

I am referencing this [article](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html).

In the article it is mentioned that the reason why `angular2` is faster than `angular1` is because `angular2` has the ability to construct an unidirectional change detection tree.

What I don't understand is that if you have `@output` and `eventEmitter` the data flow is inherently non unidirectional, since data can flow back to its parent.

For example

`Child`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'Child',
   inputs: ['myfullname'],
   outputs: ['changefirstname']
})
@View({
 template: `
   <div (click)="changefirstname()">
     {{myfullname}}
   </div>
 `
 })

 export class Child {
     public myfullname: String; 
     public myevent: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

     changefirstname(evt) {
        this.myevent.next('newfirstname');
     }
}
```

`Parent`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'Parent',
  directives: [Child]
})
@View({
 template: `
   <Child [myfullname]={{myfullname}} (myevent)="handleMyEvent($event)"></Child>
 `
 })

 export class Parent {

   this.myfullname = 'default';

   handleMyEvent(arg) {
     this.myfullname = arg;
   }
 }
```

Above we have a pretty simple setup

Whenever the child is clicked, the name gets updated in the parent, but since the child receive the name from the parent the child get updated too. We can see this is not a unidirectional data flow, since it is not top down.

We can also construct a more extreme example

```
    A
  /   \
 B     C
```

Where `C` can emit an event to `A` that changes the model for which the model is re pass down to both `C` and `B`. If we only traverse the `C` subtree for this change detection we will miss both model change in `A` and `B`

Is the article wrong? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

> since data can flow back to its parent

Indeed. But information flows *as an event* to the parent but data flows down from parent to its children.

Basically the child doesn't mutate data. Only the parent (or whatever owns the data) does.

Answer (score 0):

When a value changes, in the next change detection cycle, change detection recognizes it and updates bindings to inputs from parent to child.

When an output emits an event, then the parent is updated

and the event initiates a new change detection cycle.

This means change detection itself only propagates changes in one direction (unidirectional) from parent to child.
Changes in the other direction are propagated by other means (events) which breaks the cycle that would make it difficult if change detection itself would propagate changes in both directions.

See also http://pascalprecht.github.io/slides/angular-2-change-detection-explained

Comment: It seems angular2 is also an `O(n)` trasversal in change detection, why is the author in the slide claiming angular2 is faster than angular1. Is it only faster if you optimize angular2 like using `.push` ?

Comment: I don't know Angular1 well, but if Angular1 has two-way data-binding that can lead to cycles where it might need to iterate over the same parts of the tree several times until the model stabilizes which makes it > O(n).

Comment: But you can also construct a cycle in Angular2. Its just that the cycle is consist of data change and event instead of just data change, but either way change detection need to be fired to catch that.

Comment: In devMode Angular throws if change detection leads to data change. This works quite well to prevent cycles.